# How to validate each and every message on azure event hub for data reconciliation

Tags: eventhub

I have a requirement where i have an azure function which emit event hub message for change in Cosmos DB trigger.
So thousand of document can be modified in Azure cosmos DB which in turn will generate that many event hub messages. Is there a way to reconcile/verify this data in event hub so that to confirm that EH has all the messages?

I can write code to peak all messages from EH but looking for some better solution